# Problems in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have write the program in matlab but i do not get the image.I want to plot but it does not appear properly.

Program here:

```
clear all;
clc;
No=10^-6;
Po=10;
Rb=16000;
Tb=1/Rb;
Eb=Po.*Tb;
Da=5;
Da_db=10^(Da/10);
Nc=32;
Mc=4;
L=8;
K=3;
M=3;
j=0;

var1=No./(2.*Eb);

var2=2/(3.*Da_db.*Nc);

var3=(1+(Mc./5))*L*K-1;

Meu1=sqrt(1./(1+var1+var2.*var3));

var4=((1-Meu1)/2)^M;

var5=((1+Meu1)/2)^j;


% fact1=factorial(M-1+j);
% fact2=factorial(j);
% fact3=factorial(M-1);

n=M-1+j;
fact=factorial(n)/(factorial(j).*factorial(n-j));


for i=1:M;
    for j=0:2;
     s(i)=fact.*(((1+Meu1)/2)^j);
    end
end

s=s(i)
BER=var4.*s


semilogy(Eb/No,BER)
axis([0 64 10e-12 10e-1])
```

What is my problem?Please Help me.I want to plot a figure but this program give me a blank figure.

Answer (score 0):

You are plotting a single point and the axis limits you set do not contain that point.
Try replacing the last two lines with

```
semilogy(Eb/No, BER, 'bo');
```

and you'll see your plotted point.